# Elementary Number Theory $(a+b,\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b})=1 \text{ or } p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $(a,b)$=1, and let $p$ be an odd prime, prove that
$$(a+b,\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b})=1 \text{ or } p$$.

I thought of letting $p=2k+1,k\in\mathbb{Z}$,

then use the identity

$$a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=(a+b)(a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+a^{2k-2}b^2-\ldots+b^{2k})$$

So dividing throughout,

$$\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}=a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+a^{2k-2}b^2-\ldots+b^{2k}$$

However, after that, I am kind of stuck..

Sincere thanks for any help!

Comment: Hint: suppose that $h$ divides $a+b.$ Note that $(-a)^{k}b^{p-1-k} \equiv b^{p-1}$ (mod $h$).

Comment: For completeness, you should show that both $1$ and $p$ can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me continue the hint I wrote above. We see that if $h$ divides $a +b,$ then $\frac{a^p +b^p}{a+b} \equiv pb^{p-1}$ (mod $h$). Hence, if we let $h = {\rm gcd}(a+b,\frac{a^p +b^p}{a+b}),$ we see that $h|pb^{p-1}.$ But $h$ is coprime to $b,$ since $h |(a+b)$ and ${\rm gcd}(a,b) = 1.$ Hence $h|p,$ as required.

Later edit: Although the question does not request a proof that both $1$ and $p$ can occur, I provide one, in response to the comment of Andr\'e. If $p$ divides $a+b,$ then taking $h =p$ above shows that $\frac{a^p +b^p}{a+b} \equiv pb^{p-1} \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), so that $p$ divides ${\rm gcd}(a+b,\frac{a^p +b^p}{a+b})$ in that case, and the gcd is equal to $p$ by what has been shown already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick when dealing with $\gcd(a+b, f(a, b) )$, where

- $f(a, b)$ is a polynomial in $a$ and $b$, ideally homogenous
- $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.

The idea is that we want to factor out as much $a+b$ as we can from $f(a, b)$, and so we apply the Remainder Factor theorem which tells us that $f(a, b)$ when divided by $a+b$ leaves a remainder of $f( -b, b )$.

Hence, $ \gcd( a+b, f(a, b) ) = \gcd (a + b, f( -b, b ) )$.
In the event that $f(a, b)$ is homogenous of degree $k$, then $f(-b, b) = A b^k$, and so $\gcd(a + b, f(a, b) ) = \gcd (a + b, A)$.

In this particular case, with $f(a, b) = \frac{ a^p + b^p } { a+b}$,

- Show that $ f(-b, b ) = p b^{p-1}$.
- Hence $\gcd( a+b, f(a, b) )  = \gcd(a +b, p)$.
- In particular, $ \gcd(a+b, f(a, b) ) = p $ iff $p \mid a+b$.
- What happens for odd composite numbers $p$?